# Hibernate and Postgres large objects - freeing Blob resources in entity finalize() method

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jboss

I have an application using EJB 3.0 and Hibernate running on JBoss 4.2.3 AS and the transactions controlled by the EJB.

I was facing a problem that there was several messages on Postgres log about large objects like "ERROR:  invalid large-object descriptor: 0" and sometimes "ERROR:  large object 488450 does not exist". The result was that everything worked fine in the application but sometimes (not always) Postgres couldn't commit the transaction after the hibernate commit (after all the code in the main EJB called method being executed).

I investigated the legacy code and found a superclass of all the entities that represents file storage in the database. In this class the file is represented by a Blob attribute and it is used by getBinaryStream() method. What i found weird is what is in the finalize() method of this class as bellow:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "BIN_CONTENT", nullable = true, updatable = true)
protected Blob content;

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if (this.content != null) {
        try {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(this.content.getBinaryStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.severe("Error finalizing Blob stream");
        }
        try {
            this.content.free();
        } catch (AbstractMethodError e) {
        } catch (SQLFeatureNotSupportedException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.severe("Error finalizing Blob stream");
        }
        this.content = null;
    }
    super.finalize();
}
```

After i commented this code everything seemed to work fine. The question is:
Is that necessary? I want to understand what is going internally due the execution of this code that is causing the errors on the database side.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the code you've provided.

The first problem is `finalize()` timing.

`java.sql.Blob` implementation depends on the jdbc driver and usually the implementing class stores only identifier of the blob and when content is accessed (using `getBinaryStream()` for example) another call(s) to database is performed. This implies that at the moment when `getBinaryStream()` is invoked connection which was used to get blob should be still opened. 
But JVM doesn't provide any guaranties when finalize will be invoked so accessing Blob in finalize is incorrect.

I don't know for sure if PostgreSQL jdbc driver uses this logic for blobs but I know for sure that `java.sql.Array` implementation has this limitation (that is you cannot invoke methods of  array after connection is closed).

The second problem is that though blob mapping is defined as lazy even if client didn't use it blob field will always be loaded by `finalize()`.

In general it is responsibility of the client to perform clean up when using blobs. The pattern for usage the blob is:

```
try {
    blob = entity.getContent();
    // ... use blob
} finally {
    // ... do blob cleanup
}
```